# Laravel custom Logging in database

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to develop custom logging for Laravel. All logs are inserted into database.
I want to build it so I can add for example

```
LogMe::log('Just testing', 'GET');
```

As you see I'm passing message and method.
And LogMe file looks like

```
    <?php

namespace Modules\Log;

use Modules\Log\Entities\Log;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Client\Response;

class LogMe
{

    public static function log(Request $request, Response $response,  string $message, string $action)
    {
        return Log::create(['user_id' => Auth::id() , 'log_message' => $message, 'action' => $action, 'log_type' => 'log', 'request' => 'test']);
    }

    public static function info(string $message, string $action)
    {
        return Log::create(['user_id' => Auth::id() , 'log_message' => $message, 'action' => $action, 'log_type' => 'info']);
    }

    public static function warning(string $message, string $action)
    {
        return Log::create(['user_id' => Auth::id() , 'log_message' => $message, 'action' => $action, 'log_type' => 'warning']);
    }

    public static function error(string $message, string $action)
    {
        return Log::create(['user_id' => Auth::id() , 'log_message' => $message, 'action' => $action, 'log_type' => 'error']);
    }
}
```

And that works fine. Problem is that I want to log Request and Response as well.
When I try something like `log(Request $request, Response $response, string $message, string $action)` It gives me

> Argument 1 passed to Modules\Log\LogMe::log() must be an instance of
> Illuminate\Http\Request, string given

Any suggestions?

Comment: please show a full example of the function you created, and how you tried to use it exactly. Seems like you tried to pass a string into the function instead of a Request object.

Comment: I have edited the post.

Comment: I think forcing the request in like that only works for requests passed directly through the routes. You'll need to pass the request in yourself to the log function.

Comment: If you wrote `LogMe::log('Just testing'`... and tried to call the `log(Request $request, Response $response...` function, then clearly it won't work because `'Just testing'` is a string, it isn't a "Request" object. And there's the same problem for `'GET'` which is also a string, and isn't a "Response" object. Actually you probably just need to use one of the other functions instead like "info", "warning" or "error" which all accept strings.

Comment: you are calling a method directly, you have to pass what the signature calls for ... this is PHP ... if you are thinking about dependency injection that involves using the application container